# please help me with mod_rewrite url .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite this in .htaccess from `http://gamepanel.domain.com/system/settings.php` to `http://gamepanel.domain.com/system/settings` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule settings settings.php [L]
```